# Custom styled checkbox hover and click on label not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I discovered a really slick way to create custom styled checkboxes using pure CSS. One drawback is that you have to click on the box itself (really the label) to check the box. If you are familiar with the method of putting the actual input inside the label, you'll know this allows you to click on the label text or the box to check it. The drawback to this is you can't actually style a checkbox (because, for some reason, when it comes to CSS and forms, we all still live in purgatory.) So to get the best of both worlds I'm trying to use javascript to trigger hover and click states. I think I'm missing something either in my JS or CSS but I'm not seeing it. The classes are being applied but the CSS just isn't being applied and I'm stumped. I haven't added the click events yet. I'm still just trying to get the hover state. Hover over the box itself to see what I'm trying to do with hovering the text, too.

http://codepen.io/sinrise/pen/gPZmRm

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="subcategories">
    <li id="subcat-test">
      <div class="tmi-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="subcat-check-test" value="none" />
        <label for="subcat-check-test"></label><span>Subcategory</span>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS (SCSS)

```
.container { padding: 50px; }
ul.subcategories {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    li {
        &:hover { cursor: pointer; }
        position: relative;
        .tmi-checkbox {
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 0 15px 0;
            input[type="checkbox"] {
                visibility: hidden;
                &:checked + label:after {
                    opacity: 1;
                    // color of check inside box
                    border-color: #fff;
                }
                &:checked + label {
                    background: orange;
                    border-color: orange;
                }
            }
            label {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                width: 18px;
                height: 18px;
                border-radius: 3px;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                &:hover { cursor: pointer; }
                &:after {
                  opacity: 0;
                  content: '';
                  position: absolute;
                  width: 11px;
                  height: 7px;
                  background: transparent;
                  top: 3px;
                  left: 3px;
                  border: 3px solid #333;
                  border-top: none;
                  border-right: none;
                  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
                  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
                  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
                  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
                  transform: rotate(-45deg);
                }
                &:hover::after {
                    opacity: 0.3;
                    cursor: pointer;
                }
            }
            span {
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                margin-left: 30px;
                top: 0;
                max-width: 230px;
                color: #4a4a4a;
                left: 10px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

JS

```
$(".subcategories li").hover(function() {
  $(this).find("label").addClass("tmi-checkbox-label-hover");
  $(this).find("input").addClass("tmi-checkbox-hover");
}, function() {
  $(this).find("label").removeClass("tmi-checkbox-label-hover");
  $(this).find("input").removeClass("tmi-checkbox-hover");
});
```

Comment: Why don't you add the classes on elements when you go hover the container  div.tmi-checkbox? Or you can try to use CSS only solutions, like this pen (not mine) http://codepen.io/CreativeJuiz/pen/BiHzp

Comment: Fantastic! This works really well, no javascript, and it plays nice with responsiveness. Thanks so very much!

Answer (score 2):

Just put the `<span>Subcategory</span>` inside the label tags

`<label for="subcat-check-test"></label><span>Subcategory</span>`

I have update your code. You can check it http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJbvQw

Comment: This works great in the pen, but for some reason it's plays hell with the widths on my actual implementation. For some reason max-width isn't being honored. I'm only able to get the width to cooperate if I set a static width in pixels. min-width works, too but then it doesn't expand. http://i.imgur.com/1hhP1Ga.jpg